# How to get how many days in current month in android

Tags: android, days

I want to know the name of current date time and year and count how many days in current month

Answer (score 3):

```
int iYear = 2000;
int iMonth = Calendar.January;
int iDay = 1;

// Create a calendar object and set year and month
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay);

// Get the number of days in that month
int daysInMonth = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```